# Why does the password authentication set in the .htaccess file not work for me?

Tags: php, authentication, .htaccess, http

I want to set up a password secured file at my bplaced subdomain. I use the following .htaccess file:

```
<Files einstellungen.json>
  AuthName "This file is password protected!"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile .htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files esp32.php>
  AuthName "This script is password protected!"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile .htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Now I have the problem, that if I go to the file in the browser, it shows a dialog for the username and password.

I typed them in and then it shows a 500 HTTP Error, which says, that the error leads to the .htaccess file.

I've tried to use an absolute path for the .htpasswd file, but that led to the same result.

What is wrong with this .htaccess file?

Comment: You have a couple of options here, but foremost: Getting a 500 is an invitation to look into the Apache HTTP error-log. There you will find more information. Obtain it and append it to your question. With that information it is less guessing where (at the many places) the _internal_ server error is caused.

Comment: "I've tried to use an absolute path for the .htpasswd file" - The problem is most likely that you are using the wrong absolute filesystem path. It does _need_ to be an absolute file path. A relative URL-path (as in your current file) is certainly wrong. Either that or the pwd file cannot be read for some reason.

Comment: What @MrWhite wrote, and mind the gap/detail: _" If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the [ServerRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot)."_ from: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile

Comment: See the following related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710356/error-500-protecting-a-single-url-with-htpasswd and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122076/how-do-i-lock-a-folder-with-htaccess-file

Comment: @hakre thanks, I've tryed the wrong absolute path.
right: `/users/#USERNAME#/www/.htpasswd`
wrong: `/www/.htpasswd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MrWhite and @hakre written in the comments, it has to be an absolute path.

My mistake was, that I used an absolute path which refers to to wrong orgin.

Wrong:`/www/.htpasswd`

At bplaced would be right:`/users/#USERNAME#/www/.htpasswd`